# fitting a door handle

Tags: doors

I want to fir new handles to internal doors. My wife (boss) wants door handles with back plate. The problem is there is a 5cm hole in the doors where door knobs have been put in, and I cant get a backplate which is bigger than 4.8cm. whats the best thing for me to do?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to order them but there are all types of handle sets with bigger back plates. Some manufacturers like Baldwin, or Omni and a few others allow "a la carte" choices, where you can specify each component of the latch sets.